# Making masks with shading nodes that accounts camera ray

Tags: camera, shaders, masking

I have a problem that I want to solve if possible.

I have 2 objects (Boxes), Obj2 is above Obj1 (almost touching each other on Obj1's Z+ face). I want to draw Obj2 only in where Obj1 is visible to camera ray. So if I can see Obj1 through X-Ray the Obj2 is drawn.
I know that OpenGL has stencils, this is what I want, but I didn't find it in Blender.

---

### Example:

[image: Example]
Viewport is what I have in Blender.

Mask Passed is what I will have in the render (after shading).

Mask Failed is what will not be drawn (This is what failed the comparison inside the stencil, like a inverse mask)

---

I think Booleans won't work here because it has nothing to intersect with.

So my question is: *Is this possible without hardcoding them both in Eevee and Cycles? If I change the Loc/Rot/Scale of the camera the stencil must be calculated automatically.*

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/id_mask.html

Comment: @cegaton Thank you for this page. Some notes why I didn't find this:
1. I searched in Inputs
2. I searched in Shading not Compositing
3. Google doesn't show me Mask ID page

Comment: Sadly Eevee doesn't have this ID function. I found some walkaround with layers, I will try to use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The mask effect can be achieved with rendering objects in different scenes and combining them in compositor after.

### Compositing with Eevee:

[image: Compositor with Eevee]

### Compositing with Cycles:

[image: Compositor Nodes Cycles]